# Icons in TabNavigator and StackNavigator hides for a while when navigating (Screenshots)

Tags: react-native, icons, react-navigation, tabnavigator, stack-navigator

The Icons (Home, Search, Notification etc.) in the TabNavigator and the StackNavigator hides for a while when navigating. 
I posted when it happens in the TabNavigator.

Any idea what could be wrong?

[image: First]

[image: Second]

Comment: did you find any solution to this problem. I'm having the same problem. 

Does your problem start when you click on a tab and then the icon disappears for a while ?

Comment: @Gardezi Nope! Now when I boot my app all the icons of the navigators loading really slow.. Still searching..

Comment: Well my problem was not exactly as yours but in my case the problem was when I clicked the icon disappeared 

The reason was my computer and my cell time were not the same my cell time was not correct once I fixed it everything started too work

Hope it helps.if yes then please tell me

Comment: @Gardezi Yeah okey thanks!